# When and how to call suspend function from Android Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `suspend` function that calls POST request to the server. I want to configure some text in the activity to show the information I received from the server.

```
suspend fun retrieveInfo():String
```

I tried calling inside `onCreate`, `onResume` but crashes runtime.

```
runBlocking { 
    retrieveInfo()
}
```

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.augmentedimage/com.google.AugmentedImageActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
```

Where am I suppose to put these suspend calls (in which part of lifecycle of activity)? Should I be using something other than `runBlocking`?

Comment: Launch a coroutine from your main thread. `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { myFun() }`

Comment: Generally the favoured approach for something like this is to use a `ViewModel` and then use it's built in `viewModelScope`  (some more details in https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471)

Answer (score 15):

By default `runBlocking` runs the suspending code `block` in the thread `runBlocking` was called on.

So if you called `runBlocking` from the `Activity` callback your suspending block will be executed on the main thread, from which you **cannot** access network (query a server).

You need to switch a dispatcher in your coroutine block for that call. The simplest fix for your code would be to move the execution to the `Dispatchers.IO`.

```
runBlocking {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        retrieveInfo()
    }
}
```

---

That being said, I suggest two things (not related directly to your question):

1. Read [`Coroutines on Android`](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-i-getting-the-background-3e0e54d20bb) (this part and the following ones)

**2. Don't use `runBlocking` for your case, but define a correct `job` and use `job.launch{}`**

Comment: Your quick solution of `runBlocking` with `IO` context allows the code to run. However, unless the API call is fast enough, it still gives `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo` `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`

Comment: @user3087615 that's a whole another issue unrelated to the coroutine itself. You need to have a proper error handling for your api call.

Comment: @user3087615 also you really should follow the second point of my answer because calling `runBlocking` in Activity lifecycle methods is a really bad idea.

Comment: is there any good documentation on how to create a job and launch? I am new to kotlin and struggling to find good documentation. If you could show a short example or point to documentation, it would be awesome.

Comment: @user3087615 my post consists of a great post on the subject

Comment: Not really, please, provide a better one :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write in activity:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val scope = CoroutineScope(newSingleThreadContext("name"))

fun doSomething() {
    scope.launch { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: `newSingleThreadContext` is obsolete.